# Thanos Receiver Data Retention for 3 hours

Tags: thanos

[image]I did set up 5 replicas of Thanos Receivers with 3 hours of data retention.
I verified that ULID folders created every 2 hours are being created and being deleted after 3 hours.
However, my problem is, the data in the wal directory seems keep on increasing and not being deleted after 3 hours. I was trying to find any information about it in Thanos Documentation if this is an expected behavior. We only provision 20Gi of pvc, and we cannot afford to increase it as part of company's cost effectivity goal.

Is there any information where in I can make the wal directory in Thanos Receivers data storage can be deleted as the ULID directories do?

Expectation:
Data folders inside the wal directory would be deleted the same way as the ULID directories get deleted after 3 hours.

Please give me some light. Thank you.

Comment: I'd recommend trying other remote storage solutions for Prometheus such as Cortex, m3db or [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/), since they may require lower amounts of resources (disk space, RAM, CPU, network bandwidth) comparing to Thanos receiver  It is easy to evaluate all these solutions in parallel by configuring multiple `remote_write->url` entries in Prometheus configs. In this case Prometheus replicates scraped data to all the configured remote storage systems.

Comment: Hi @valyala, thanks for the reply. I found out that the issue is that the ULID are not truly being deleted after 3 hours. I think it was 30-40 mins before they get truly deleted based on the version we have. I would love to explore other tech, however my superiors wants me to use Thanos Receivers for the current archi design that we have. Appreciate your response. Thank you.